# UIDocumentInteractionController() swift

Tags: ios, swift

I created a file and I want to share it via `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

I am unsure on how to obtain the URL from the `documentsPath` and destination path where I saved my file

```
        let someText = NSString(string: "Test")
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

        let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Data.txt")
        var error:NSError?
        
        let written = someText.writeToFile(destinationPath,
            atomically: true,
            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
            error: &error)
        
        if written{
            println("Successfully stored the file at path \(destinationPath)")

  let dic = UIDocumentInteractionController()

   self.dic.URL = url
            let v = sender as UIView
            let ok = self.dic.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(
                v.bounds, inView: v, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Revise your code to the following

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var docController:UIDocumentInteractionController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let someText = NSString(string: "Test")
        if let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as? String {

        let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Data.txt")
        var error:NSError?

        let written = someText.writeToFile(destinationPath,
            atomically: true,
            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
            error: &error)

        if written{
            println("Successfully stored the file at path \(destinationPath)")
            }
       if let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: destinationPath) {
            docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: url)
        }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sendFile(sender:AnyObject) {
    docController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(sender.frame, inView:self.view, animated:true)
    }

}
```

Now wire up the IBAction to a button in the storyboard. Next:

1. click on the blue project icon in the left sidebar and then select
   **Info** from the horizontal menu.
2. expand **Document Types** and enter "txt" in the **Name** field and
   "public.data, public.content" in the **Types** field
3. now expand **Exported UTIs** and enter "txt" in the **Description**
   field, "kUTTypeText" in the **Identifier** field and
   "public.data, public.content" in the **Conforms to field**

So that everything looks like this:

[image]

You can now build and run the app to test.