# Switching back to the app after Saving to iCloud Drive from UIDocumentInteractionController removes navigation hierarchy

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I am using UIDocumentInteractionController to save the document at specified URL to iCloud Drive, but the problem is that when I switch back to the app after saving/cancel from iCloud, my original view controller is no longer present, the entire navigation hierarchy is removed and the root view controller is shown.

I am presenting the options in the menu from a view controller that is presented view controller.

```
extension ADDTextChatViewController: AddReceiverFileDelegate {
    func downloadTapped(url: String?, cell: AddReceiverTableViewCell) {
        guard let urlString = url else {return}
        shareAction(withURLString: urlString, cell: cell)
    }
}

extension ADDTextChatViewController {
    func share(url: URL, cell: AddReceiverTableViewCell) {
        documentInteractionController.url = url
        documentInteractionController.uti = url.typeIdentifier ?? "public.data, public.content"
        documentInteractionController.name = url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent
        documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: cell.btnDownload.frame, in: view, animated: true)
    }
    func shareAction(withURLString: String, cell: AddReceiverTableViewCell) {
        guard let url = URL(string: withURLString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            let tmpURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
                .appendingPathComponent(response?.suggestedFilename ?? "fileName.png")
            do {
                try data.write(to: tmpURL)
            } catch { print(error) }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.share(url: tmpURL, cell: cell)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}

extension URL {
    var typeIdentifier: String? {
        return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier
    }
    var localizedName: String? {
        return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.localizedNameKey]))?.localizedName
    }
}
```

What shall I do in order to remain on the same view controller from which I called this method, after switching back from iCloud?

Comment: Could you please share your code from where you are dismissing the interaction controller.

Comment: @DheerajD I haven't added any code for that, it is managed automatically right now or may be I am not able to check whether it is dismissed or not, because when I switch back to my app, my view controller is no longer present, but if I cancel the document interaction controller itself, then the action sheet just dismisses and my view controller is still present

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399341/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-swift

Comment: can you show your app delegate, what you are doing in applicationDidBecomeActive,  applicationWillEnterForeground

Comment: @DheerajD but I don't want to share, I want to save to iCloud drive/dropbox whatever suggestions are provided from the action sheet

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh Do I need to do anything there? I am not doing anything in the methods you mentioned

Comment: As far I think why your view controller is removed is main issue and root view is coming on a resume, so maybe you are removing or adding while app becomes background or foreground respectively or presenting and dismissing wrongly?

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh yes but I am not removing or adding anything during the app transitions

Comment: Please share your cellForRow method code here. Is there anything wrong happing after cell's button tap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that in order to maintain the navigation stack, you need to pass the navigation controller into the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` method `documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview`.

In the document for this delegate method it is stated that *If presenting atop a navigation stack, provide the navigation controller in order to animate in a manner consistent with the rest of the platform*

So here's what my code looks like now, after implementing this delegate method.

```
extension ADDTextChatViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        guard let navVC = self.navigationController else {
            return self
        }
        return navVC
    }
}
```

And I added

```
documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

instead of

```
documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
```

which will first show the preview of the document like this (Please see that, this preview will be pushed from my `ADDTextChatViewController`)

[image]

As you can see in the bottom left, the arrow will then provide options such as below, depending upon the document type

[image]

So now when I switch back to my application after transitioning to iCloud Drive/ any of the options in the action sheet, my navigation stack is not removed.

I hope this helps someone in future as well.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try change your code to this and Try:

```
func share(url: URL, cell : UITableViewCell) {
        documentInteractionController.url = url
        documentInteractionController.uti = url.typeIdentifier ?? "public.data, public.content"
        documentInteractionController.name = url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent
        documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: cell.btn.frame, in: view, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: I have a table view cell which has the button, so do you suggest adding this entire code in the tableviewcell class?

Comment: Please try this and let me know.

Comment: Ok let me try this one

Comment: I need to see your code how you are doing all the things.

Comment: Sure, let me share within some time... :)

Comment: I have updated the question with code, see the delegate method, I am passing the cell instance in the view controller that has table view...delegate is called on tap of button in tableviewcell class